# How stream passes incremental?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand how `Stream` works and have following `Stream` implementation:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A] {

  def toList: List[A] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(s: Stream[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] = s match {
      case Cons(h, t) => go(t(), h() :: acc)
      case _ => acc
    }

    go(this, List()).reverse
  }

  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B =
    this match {
      case Cons(h, t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f))
      case _ => z
    }

  def map[B](f: A => B): Stream[B] =
    this.foldRight(Stream.empty[B])((x, y) => Stream.cons(f(x), y))

  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
    this.foldRight(Stream.empty[A])((h, t) => if (f(h)) Stream.cons(h, t) else t)

}

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]


object Stream {

  def cons[A](hd: => A, t1: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = t1

    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

}
```

and the code that is using `Stream`:

```
Stream(1,2,3,4).map((x) => {
  println(x)
  x + 10
}).filter((x) => {
  println(x)
  x % 2 == 0
}).toList
```

as output I've got:

```
1
11
2
12
3
13
4
14
res4: List[Int] = List(12, 14)
```

As you can see on the output, there is no intermediate result, the source will be pass one for one, how is that possible?

I can not image, how does it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at what the methods you used do on `Stream`:

`map` and `filter` are both implemented with `foldRight`. To make it clearer, let's inline `foldRight` inside `map` (the same can be done with `filter`), using the referential transparency principle:

```
def map[B](f: A => B) = this match {
  case Cons(h, t) => Stream.cons(f(h()), t().map(f))
  case _ => Empty
}
```

Now, where in this code is `f` evaluated? Never, since `Stream.cons` parameters are call-by-name, so we only give the description for the new stream, not its values.

Once you are convinced of this fact, you can easily see that the same will apply for `filter`, so we can move forward to `toList`.

It will evaluate each element in the `Stream`, putting the values in a `List` that will be reversed at the end.

But evaluating an element of the `Stream` which has been filtered and mapped is precisely reading the description of the values, so the actual functions are evaluated here. Hence the console output in order: first the `map` function is called then the `filter` function, for each element, one at a time (since we are now on the lazily mapped and filtered `Stream`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.